Prove that the integral $\int_0^t \sigma (s,X_s)dB_s$ is a martingale
Let $dX_t=a(t,X_t)dt+\sigma (t,X_t)dB_t$.
Let $\sigma (t,X_t)$ satisfies Lipschitz condition and linear growth condition.
Prove that $$\int_0^t \sigma (s,X_s)dB_s$$ is a martingale ($B_t$ is a brownian motion).
Do I need additional conditions here?
How to approach this problem?

We can deduce that $E[\int_0^T|\sigma(t,X_t)|^2dt]<\infty$ from the existence theorem (see e.g. Schilling Th.21.13 p. 396). For simplicity here the process is $\mathbb{R}$-valued over $[0,T]$, starts at $X_0=x_0\in \mathbb{R}$ and $a,\sigma :[0,T]\times \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$. From the linear growth condition we have $|\sigma(t,x)|^2\leq M_T^2(1+|x|)^2\leq 2M_T^2(1+|x|^2)$ for some $M_T>0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and the existence theorem states that the unique solution satisfies $E[\sup_{s\leq T}|X_s|^2]\leq k_T(1+|x_0|)^2$ for some $k_T>0$. So
$$\begin{aligned}E\bigg[\int_0^T|\sigma(t,X_t)|^2dt\bigg]&\leq 2M_T^2\bigg(T+E\bigg[\int_0^T|X_t|^2dt\bigg]\bigg)\\
&\leq 2TM_T^2\bigg(1+E\bigg[\sup_{t\leq T}|X_t|^2\bigg]\bigg)<\infty
\end{aligned}$$
as we wanted to show.

how did you show that $2M_T^2\bigg(T+E\bigg[\int_0^T|X_t|^2dt\bigg]\bigg)\leq 2TM_T^2\bigg(1+E\bigg[\sup_{t\leq T}|X_t|^2\bigg]\bigg)$?

@eMathHelp $|X_t|^2\leq \sup_{t\leq T}|X_t|^2$ for all $t\leq T$ so $\int_0^T|X_t|^2dt\leq \sup_{t\leq T}|X_t|^2\int_0^Tdt=T\cdot \sup_{t\leq T}|X_t|^2$

What about $E\bigg[\int_0^T|\sigma(t,X_t)|^2dt\bigg]\leq 2M_T^2\bigg(T+E\bigg[\int_0^T|X_t|^2dt\bigg]\bigg)$? You've bounded the expectation, but there are no bounds mentioned for the expectation.

@eMathHelp From the linear growth condition on $\sigma$ we know that $\int_0^T|\sigma(t,X_t)|^2dt\leq 2M_T(T+\int_0^T|X_t|^2dt)$. Then, take expectation on both sides.

Thank you very much! We didn't use Lipschitz condition, right? It was used just in the theorem.

Indeed we just used the linear growth condition for the inequality, while the Lipschitz condition is there for the referenced theorem to hold.

How does finiteness of second moment show that this is a martingale?

Couldn't we just right that $E\left[\int_0^T|\sigma(t,X_t)|^2dt\right]\leq E\left[\int_0^T M_T^2(1+|x|^2)dt\right]=TM_T^2(1+|x|^2)$. Why do we need the $sup$ condition?

@eMathHelp (1) please see the third paragraph of this answer. (2) No, you are fixing some $x$ on one side and you can't do it. The linear growth condition is on the second argument of $\sigma$.

Is there a proof of this statement?

Please look at Klenke's Th.25.18 p. 570 @eMathHelp
